# GNU make scope of variable

Tags: build, gnu-make

I have some makefile:

```
$(PROGRAM_NAME): index.o
    @echo "linking"
    @echo $(index_o)
    //linking

export index_o:=.
index.o:
    $(MAKE) -C some_dir index.o
```

at some_dir makefile

```
export index_o:=$(index_o)/index.o
index.o:
    @echo "compiling"
    @echo $(index_o)
    //compiling
```

output:

compiling
./index.o
linking
.

need output:

compiling
./index.o
linking
./index.o

How to share changes of variable to the parent make thread?
May be I need real global variable...
I have read http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Recursion.html
but not found

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* push variable back to parent processes.

You may be interested in reading [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/). Short-short version: recursion isn't necessary for controlling large builds and causes trouble.